# iMessaging an iPhone from an iPad

Tags: ipad, wifi, messages

I am trying to iMessage an iPhone 4S using its phone number. When I press send, the sending progress runs to ~90% and pauses. Then, after about 1-2 minutes, a red exclamation point appears. This happens every time. My WiFi connection is great. What's the problem? I have a 16 GB iPad WiFi running iOS 5.

Answer (score -2):

Why not try iPhone's email address? As far as I know, iMessage is registered by e-mail, not phone number.

Comment: Basically, if you type in the email address and it's registered with iMessage, your message and send button will turn blue, so you'll know it's working.

Comment: Issue resolved but a mystery.  Above advice changed nothing.  When the wifi iPad and 4s were brought together on the same router Imessage immediately started to work.  Later back on the original setup it also worked!